# getting issue linke ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar SQL state: 22023 in postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.1

```
SELECT rec FROM rec WHERE ( et && array['Tt']::text[] ) AND rec ? '@i' AND EXISTS ( SELECT true FROM jsonb_array_elements(e -> '@i') AS tl WHERE CASE WHEN tl #>> '{@t,0}' = 'p' THEN EXISTS ( SELECT true FROM jsonb_array_elements(tl -> 'h') AS miv WHERE miv ->> '@v' ~ '.*best.*'::text ) WHEN toplevel #>> '{@t,0}' = 'r' THEN EXISTS ( SELECT true FROM jsonb_array_elements(tl -> 'o') AS miv WHERE miv ->> '@i' ~ '.*best.*'::text ) WHEN toplevel #>> '{@t,0}' = 'd' THEN tl ->> '@v' ~ '.*best.*'::text ELSE false END ) GROUP BY rec LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

I am getting this issue while executing  above this query

```
ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar SQL state: 22023
```

please provide the solution for this problem thanks